# Dockerhub showing image pulled a few seconds ago

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I checked my dockerhub account about a month ago and my private docker repository was showing the status of `image was pulled a few seconds ago` but I had not pulled the image. Then I changed the password of the account and today it is still showing the same status as shown in the following image.

[image]

Is this some kind of security risk or something else? I searched on different forums but could not find the details...

Comment: Checking some similar topics it can be a security issue or automatic tool to monitor like `ouroboros` or `watchtower`

Comment: It's entirely possible that just hitting the Hub UI may trigger a pull in some cases, e.g. to query metadata from the image manifest/config like what OS and architectures are provided by that image. I see multiple pulls on new public images, and figure at least some of them are automated scanners, but doubt that would be all of the pulls since the image hadn't been advertised yet.